# How can you set up multiple web clients on one machine

Tags: webrtc

Is there any way to do this? I am working on a webRTC application and of course I need to test it. For that I need a connection between at least 2 peers and those peers can't be the same. For the work I had i used an old laptop but I need to test also the functionality of multiple connections and for that I would need another machine. Is there any way around this? I tried using different browsers, windows or tabs but it all didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try VM : install two or more linux in virtual box for example